# Is it possible to keep parameter as an exponent in PyTorch?

Tags: parameters, pytorch

I am running a program in which an intermediate step returns a tensor (say, T). The tensor does not contain parameters but is just real numbers.

I want to use a parameter at exponent for T. Let us name the parameter as x. So, the intermediate step should return T^x now.

I tried to train the model, but the value of x after the first backward pass is becoming `nan`.

If I use multiplication instead of exponentiation i.e., Tx instead of T^x, then the training is going well without any `nan` values.

Is it possible to pass the parameter as an exponent in PyTorch? If yes, then how can I train for x?

Answer (score 0):

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributions as dd

log_std = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # Define the log of the parameter as an nn.Parameter, this is what we want to optimise
mean = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1])) # A normal parameter

optim = torch.optim.SGD([log_std, mean], lr=0.001) # Standard optimiser
target = dd.Normal(5,5) # Target distribution to match

for i in range(50):
optim.zero_grad()

```
std = torch.exp(log_std)  # Define the transformation we want to apply to the parameter to using it in the distribution
dist = dd.Normal(loc=mean, scale=std)  # Define the distribution.

samples = dist.rsample((1000,)) # Sample our model, note no reference to log_std

cost = -(target.log_prob(samples) - dist.log_prob(samples)).sum() # KL divergence cost metric
cost.backward()
optim.step()
print(i)
print(mean, std, cost)
print()
```